# Free or inexpensive VCS with "Lock" instead of "Merge"?

Tags: version-control

I've been using several VCS systems and wondered:

Is there any free or inexpensive VCS with ability to lock files instead of constantly merging?

Almost all the open-source VCSs out there support merge... but if you generate 1 too many revisions, there is too much to merge and after while, source code goes crazy trying to deal with all the merges.

Problem:
We have a team that generates ~ 100+ changes per day and merging a team of changes leaves us swamped with many, many changes each developer has to commit.

Any ideas for a better solution than merge?

Using HG (Tried GIT, Bazaar, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/) allows you to [lock individual files](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html). There's no support for locking whole directories though.

Answer (score 0):

SourceGear has a free source control product as long as it's only used by 1 developer.

www.sourcegear.com

Comment: If it's only being used by one developer, why would you need locking?

Comment: In case you work from home on your laptop, like I do, as well as an office PC.  I can't ever remember which files I've modified.

Comment: I've never used it, but CVS is quite popular.

Comment: If you're going to go with CVS, you might as well go with SVN :P In my completely unqualified opinion, CVS is really only popular with projects that used it before SVN...

Comment: I need locking because I get around 50+ merges which is impossible to keep track-of.